# Tracking a Page with Multiple Google Analytics Accounts

Tags: google-analytics

I used to be able to use two different Google Analytics accounts on a single page with the old ga.js.

This is how I used to do it:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22766576-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-OTHER-ID-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
...
```

Google Analytics now defaults to use tag manager's gtag.js and looks like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-74053665-19"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-74053665-19');
</script>
```

The UA id is embeded in the JS call as well as in the config. It doesn't look like it's possible to fire two visits for two separate accounts anymore. Does anyone have any other solutions?

Comment: This seems to be covered by the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/, scroll to the end of the page.

Comment: Thank you! Should have checked the actual documentation. Could not find a good result through Google or otherwise.